# Word VBA to Format Headers and Footers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word report that is system generated as follows:

- Title Page
- Exec Summary
- TOC
- Section 1
- Section 2
- Section 3
- Appendix TOC
- Appendix A
- Appendix B

I am looking for a macro that will add a header to each section that matches the Section title.  I also need roman numeral page numbers in the footer for Exec summary and TOC, then restart page numbers at 1 for Sections 1- 3.  Then no page numbers in the Appendix Sections.  I have seen posts that help in adding page numbers but not anything that changes based on the section.  Can anyone provide help on this more complex header and page number problem?

Note sometimes there are different numbers of sections and Appendices

Comment: Why not just write your own? Have you tried?

Comment: You can record your own macro to get started, and then come here with questions about it.